# Android checkable menu item. Choosing the position of the CheckBox

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

I have a menu with checkable items. I want to put the CheckBox first and the Text to the right of the CheckBox. Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this using `menu items`. What you can do, is use a custom Toolbar with a custom `ImageView`(aligned right) with the image `src` as the **overflow icon** (the one with 3 vertical dots). Also create a custom view(let's say `checkBoxList`) in your layout, which contains the text to the right of checkbox, the way you want it. Keep this `checkBoxList` aligned to the top right of your parent layout (super easy if you are using `ConstraintLayout`). Also, keep the visibility of this List to `invisible`. When overflow icon get's clicked, set the visibility of `checkBoxList` to visible. Also, have an `onClickListener` on the parent Layout, where you set the visibility of checkBoxList back to invisible( So that when the user clicks on anywhere outside checkBoxList, it closes).